# Windows 7 ISO - Difficulty: No torrents

Tags: windows-7

My laptop os died on me and I need an ISO for windows 7 to put on it. I don't have internet at the house I'm currently staying at for the next month and I cant use a torrent at work.

Anyone know of a site that still has a copy of the ISO up?

Comment: In life, I assume the best about people. But not on the Internet.

Comment: Until you get your own **legitimate** copy in hand again, you could download and use the Windows 7 Enterprise 90-day Trial, available here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/evalcenter/cc442495.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a TechNet or MSDN subscription or are a certified MS partner you can get it there. If not, then it's not legal and you probably shouldn't be asking for it on this forum.

Comment: But I literally have 5 copies at my house. Its just over a thousand miles away.

Comment: Perhaps... FedEx?

Comment: That's like saying "I have 10kg of smack at home, but I can't get to it, can I have some of yours?" - still doesn't make it legal.

Comment: If one has a license for a particular piece of software, does that give the user the right to obtain that licensed software by any method, or is it in fact illegal to torrent it or otherwise download it "out of band" from the manufacturer?

Answer (score 0):

It is available on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com) in ISO format.